# MySQL command to get just count of repeating varchars

Tags: php, sql

I have store user language in my database, from this data i want to make a statistics. But to say true i am thinking about making statement which "Go to database and give me COUNT() of each language"

And output shoud looks like:

```
EN - 10
PL - 8
CS - 6
RO -21
```

I can do it with multiple selects like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) language FROM users WHERE language = "EN"
SELECT COUNT(*) language FROM users WHERE language = "CS"
```

But this is pretty stupid way in my eyes and even bad for database.

Is there someone who can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT language, COUNT(*) 
FROM users
GROUP BY language
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: It works perfectly, is there a chance to make it order from highest number to smallest?

Comment: Add ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), language FROM users GROUP BY language
```

If you want the result in string format:

```
SELECT CONCAT(language, ' - ', COUNT(*)) FROM users GROUP BY language
```

Answer (score 2):

As easy as

```
SELECT language, COUNT(*)
FROM users
GROUP BY language
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't use groub by

```
 SELECT language, 
        COUNT(*) as lang_count 
 FROM users 
 GROUP BY language 
 ORDER BY language
```

Comment: is there a need for order by clause?

Comment: maybe ... when OP whant to give the result out in ordered way .. should an example for him is not nessecarry

Answer (score 2):

Use this  -  SELECT COUNT(*),language FROM users GROUP BY language